# Simple WCF inaccessible from web browser

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to access from my web browser a simple WCF service but nothing except a blank page is shown (I am using the framework .net 4.0),

The url im trying to access:
http://localhost:50269/ConnectorService/web/SynchronizeRessources

The service contract:

```
namespace WcfDMEConnector
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IConnectorService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SynchronizeRessources();
    }
}
```

and this is the web.config serviceModel section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="WcfDMEConnector.ConnectorService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50269/ConnectorService/web" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfDMEConnector.IConnectorService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50269/ConnectorService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Two things come to mind.  First, your method returns void, so if it is executing, there's nothing to show for it.  Second, I'm pretty sure that you're missing the proper attribute on the method for RESTful WCF - I think it's `[WebGet]`.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer, I just wrote the Service Contract who is an interface, the class who implement this contract is not helpful, the SynchronizeRessources() is empty with a breakpoint in it to check if it is called. I tried with [WebGet] and I have the same issue.